# Winsock send multiple packets api?

Tags: tcp, winsock, winsock2

I've noticed that I'm losing a lot of server time in calls to send(). I have a service which sends high-frequency small packets to a moderate number of clients (>10, <100).

I suspect that recent OS patches, which have made syscalls slow, might be contributing.

I feel like I want a way to supply a bunch of sockets/packets to a single syscall, and it will do the many send() calls internally, reducing API time.

Does anything like this exist? Are there any hidden or niche API's available?

Linux has batching send functions...

Comment: You might try using `WSASend()`, you can pass in multiple input buffers to send. But more likely, your slowness issue is due to Send Coalescing via the "Nagle Algorithm", where the OS buffers outgoing data so it can generate more efficient network packets. That can introduce delays, especially when sending lots of small packets. If send speed is important, try enabling the socket's `TCP_NODELAY` option via `setsockopt()` to disable that extra buffering.

Comment: If that is still not fast enough for you, consider using WinSock's [Registered I/O (RIO)](http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2011/10/windows-8-registered-io-networking-extensions.html) API, which allows you to pre-register your data buffers with the socket kernel to minimum the need for copying data around in memory.

Comment: If send is buffering, surely it should take the packet, but then return to the calling process immediately (and continue to buffer/transmit the packet in its own background thread). Why would send coalescing affect API calling time?
To be clear, it's not how long it takes to send I'm concerned about, it's how long the send() function takes to execute, which I call a lot for a lot of sockets with small buffers.

Comment: I'll look into registered I/O... do you suspect a memcpy into a send buffer is taking the time? I doubt that, because I can serialise the packet to be transmit (which involves an elaborate call tree of C++ stream style api calls) in less time. No way a memcpy of N bytes can take longer than the complex serialisation code to produce those N bytes...